# Disable WIndows 7 Backup in Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, backup

I recently upgraded my Windows 7 machine to Windows 8. I am now using the new file history feature within Windows 8 as part of my backup strategy. My problem is that I had previously used the old Windows 7 backup solution before upgrading. Now I am in Windows 8 and still receiving messages about the Windows 7 backup.

I disabled the scheduled service that actually does the backup, which fixed most of the issues, but I am still getting the following message about the back up disk being full (which isn't even the case):

[image]

From this dialog I can get to the following settings screen:

[image]

I for the life of me can't find any way to actually disable the old backup system though. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be most appreciative!

Comment: You don't because Windows 8 is designed to migrate the Backup and Restore settings from from Windows 7.  You can force it to be disabled by deleting the following registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsBackup